# Positioning of toc, chapters, bibliography in book class

Tags: positioning, document-classes

In `\documentclass{mwbk or book}` chapters, table of contents, bibliography default are located at some distance from the top of the page/header. Does anyone have an idea how to move their location on the top of the page? Do I need to change something in the `book.cls/mwbk.cls` file? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) *always*

Comment: You should **not** edit an established class file directly, use the `xpatch` tools (as Harish has done in his answer)

Answer (score 3):

Both starred and regular chapters in `book` class have `50pt` space from the top of the page. If you want to get rid of them add the following in your preamble

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

If you want some other distance, you can add so:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{20\p@}}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{20\p@}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Code for no space:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext,showframe}   %% just for demo
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}     %% for un-starred chapters
\xpatchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}    %% for starred chapters
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]