# Moving position of Chapter title

Tags: positioning

How can I reduce the distance between "Chapter 4" and the top of the page?

```
% Customize the placement of the chapter title in the header
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{%
    \vspace{-0.5cm}% Adjust the value to move the chapter title up or down
    #1%
  }{}%
}
```

Have tried this but nothing happend.

[image]

Comment: the chaper heading (in fact the entire chapter command) is not defined in latex itself but in whatever files you are loading into the document you have not shown. It's hard to tell you how to change a definition if you don't say how it is defined.

Comment: Besides what @DavidCarlisle has said, `\chaptermark` is the text of the chapter title for use in the running head; it has nothing to do with the title placement.  Also, do you wish to change this in only one chapter or in all chapters?

Comment: I want to change the placement in all chpater. I have a template provided by my university but as I've seen so far there nothing defined about the chapter.

Answer (score 0):

The KOMA-Script classes provide configuration of this distance, e.g.

```latex
\documentclass[emulatestandardclasses]{scrbook}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt]{chapter}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\chapter{Simulation Results}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`memoir` also provides configuration options for chapters.

With the standard classes, you'd need a package like `titlesec` or [patch `\@makechapterhead` and `\@makeschapterhead`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237725/277964).

With other classes there could be other solutions.